# use "-I" to define g++ include path:why it only works when I set ".../include" instead of ".../include/boost"?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

My application need boost lib. There is a boost lib in /usr/lib and boost include in /usr/include/boost, but they aren's what I need. So I compile new boost lib in my home , /home/js/anaconda/.../include/boost and /home/js/anaconda/.../lib.

To use boost in home, I use "-I/home/js/anaconda/.../include/boost" to define the include path, however, It complain error because it find boost in the "/usr/..." path. Then I try use "-I/home/js/anaconda/.../include" (the parent directory) and it works fine!

My question is
1)why it works when I specify the parent directory "/home/.../include" instead of "/home/.../include/boost"? what is the right directory I should specify when I use "-I"?

2)when I use "-I" to specify some directory, will these directory always be the one prior to the /usr directory?

Comment: *How* do you include the header files?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hello,thanks for reply. The application include header files by "#include<boost/...>". !!!wow, is this the reason? if I change it into "#include<...>"(delete "boost"), it will works fine for "-I -I/home/js/anaconda/.../include/boost"?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. The header file path is appended to the search paths to find the files. With that said, you should not really add `boost` to your `-I`search path, as that could create collisions (two header files from different libraries could have the same name).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got iy,thank you! By the way, if I set `-I` to point the Include file path, will the compiler always find the include file in the `-I` path prior to the system Include file path?

Comment: Yes those paths added with `-I` should come before the "standard" paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common practice (but not mandatory) to include all the header files of a library into its own directory. This has a few advantages:

- When you look for a header file, you don't need to look through the header files of other libraries.
- When you read a file with include directives, you can see all the headers that belong to the same library because they start in the same base directory.

When you use `-I` preprocessor flag to add a directory to the include search path, that directory can either:

- Belong to your current project: in the case you have your files organised in directories it may become handy.
- Be a part of an external dependency: be it a system library or a dependency installed in a directory of your own. These directories' path end in `include` following the [filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

In the particular case of boost, the intended use is to `-I/path-to-boost-install/include` flag and then use an include directive such as `#include <boost/optional/optional.hpp>` to use one of the libraries in that installation.

The best advice is to read the documentation and look for examples before you start using a library. In the case of boost, you can read the [getting started on Unix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) or [getting started on Windows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) pages:

> It's important to note the following:
>
> - The path to the boost root directory (often /usr/local/boost_1_75_0) is sometimes referred to as $BOOST_ROOT in
>   documentation and mailing lists .
> - To compile anything in Boost, you need **a directory containing** the boost/ subdirectory in your #include path.
> - Since all of Boost's header files have the .hpp extension, and live in the boost/ subdirectory of the boost root, your Boost #include
>   directives will look like:
>
> ```
>     #include <boost/whatever.hpp>
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>     #include "boost/whatever.hpp"
> ```
>
> depending on your preference regarding the use of angle bracket includes.